# Ajax error in the Tags auto-comp in drupal 7

Tags: drupal-7

I am building a website using drupal 7

I have taxonomy tags but when the user click in the tags feild it alert this error

```
An AJAX HTTP error occurred.
HTTP Result Code: 200
Debugging information follows.
Path: http://www.mydomain.com/taxonomy/autocomplete/field_tags
StatusText: OK
ResponseText:
```

I tried to disable all the external Ajax functions with no luck

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this problem, and it was related to a node access module that I had installed.

By default, if a node access module is installed but does not create one or more grants for a specific node, Drupal will create a default grant giving view access to the 'all' realm (all users) if the node is published. The node access module I was using was granting the user view and edit access on a specific node, but for a realm other than the default (all). Since this grant was created for the node, Drupal skipped creating the default grant, which is the grant that the autocomplete widget uses to determine if the user has permissions to view and reference the current node.

So, to ensure a user can reference an entity via the autocomplete widget, the Drupal default grant giving view access to the 'all' realm, must exist for the node being edited.